# Why isn't this example of call by reference not working?

Tags: php

I am clearing the concept of call-by-reference.Can anyone please explain the code lines below shown as an example of call-by-reference?

```
 <?php
    function test(){
        $result = 10;
        return $result;
    }
    function reference_test(&$result){
        return $result;
    }
    reference_test($result);
 ?>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "not working". What did you expect to have? What result do you get?

Comment: I want the value 10 when calling reference_test function, but it is doesn't displaying anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. `$result` is never set and the test function is never called.
2. You do a pass by reference on the wrong function. A pass by reference is to change the variable inside and outside the function.

Here is the solution, changed the function a bit to show you the difference. You don't need to return the variable you changed by reference.

```
// Pass by ref: because you want the value of $result to change in your normal code.
// $nochange is pass by value so it will only change inside the function.
function test(&$result, $nochange){ 
    $result = 10;
    $nochange = 10;
}
// Just returns result
function reference_test($result){ 
    return $result;
}

$result = 0; // Set value to 0
$nochange = 0;
test($result, $nochange); // $result will be 10 because you pass it by reference in this function
// $nochange wont have changed because you pass it by value.
echo reference_test($result); // echo's 10
echo reference_test($nochange); // echo's 0
```